# Regex, optional match in url

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, option-type

I spend a couple of hour with no good result (maybe my mood is not helping about it).

I am trying to build a regex to help me match both urls:

```
/reservables/imagenes/4/editar/6
/reservables/imagenes/4/subir
```

As you note above, the last segment in the first url `6` is not present at the end of the second url, because this segments is optional here. So I need to match both urls in one regex, for that, I have tried this:

```
reservables/(editar|imagenes)/([0-9]+)/(imagen|editar|actualizar|subir)/([0-9]+)
```

That works fine only for the first url. So, reading a few notes about regex it suggest me that I need the `?` symbol, right? So, I tried this one, but it did not work:

```
reservables/(editar|imagenes)/([0-9]+)/(imagen|editar|actualizar|subir)/([0-9]+)?
```

Well, I do not what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put the `?` around the `/` as well, like so:

```
reservables/(editar|imagenes)/([0-9]+)/(imagen|editar|actualizar|subir)(?:/([0-9]+))?
```

You can see that it matches correctly on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=reservables/%28editar%7Cimagenes%29/%28%5B0-9%5D%2b%29/%28imagen%7Ceditar%7Cactualizar%7Csubir%29%28?:/%28%5B0-9%5D%2b%29%29?&str=/reservables/imagenes/4/editar/6%0D%0A/reservables/imagenes/4/subir).

Comment: Well, works excellent. Just one question, why you put the `?:` at the beggining of the optional segment? does it work as a "conditional"?

Comment: If `?:` is added immediately after a parenthesis, it means "Don't capture what's inside this group." I assumed you didn't care about the `/` and only cared about the number.

Comment: Yes! `/` was not included. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

This one will work:

```
reservables/(editar|imagenes)/([0-9]+)/(imagen|editar|actualizar|subir)/([0-9]*)
```

Comment: I will re-check and advice in a couple of minutes

Comment: Well, I have test it some regex tester and it does not match both urls